# Code that won't compile in C, C++ and Obj-C with a specific error message

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macros

I'm replacing one C-style macro with another.

```
#define OldMacro(…) {…}

#define NewMacro(…) {…}
```

I'd like to rewrite the old version of the macro so that it fails to compile with a specific error message, i.e. something like: "OldMacro() is deprecated; use NewMacro() instead."  Is this possible?

Also, I'd like this to work in C, C++ and Objective-C.

Comment: `#define OldMacro(...) char OldMacroIsDeprecatedUseNewMacroInstead[0]`

Comment: @MooingDuck: That won't work if your compiler (e.g., gcc by default) permits zero-sized arrays.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Or `@` to force a syntax error if you use the macro.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might want to take a look at question 10.4 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Some compilers might accept `@` (I know several accept `$`).  The advantage of the invalid array size is that the name of the thing gets printed in the error message, wheras `@` probably won't.

Comment: @MooingDuck: It's a pity you can't have a `#error` directive in a macro definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this macro definition:

```
#define OLD_MACRO()  (error_use_of_OLD_MACRO_is_deprecated = 0)
```

Comment: clever, that works in more situations than the array trick I think

Comment: @MooingDuck do you know one at which it doesn't work except if someone defined a non-const error_use_of_OLD_MACRO_is_deprecated integer-compatible variable?